# Unable to login to sftp with a new non-shell user

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

> Prologue: I am on an old Ubuntu 14. Sorry.

I created a new user

```
sudo adduser --shell /bin/false alessandra
```

Now I have `/home/alessandra`

```
mirko@ubuntu:/home$ ls -la
... [cut] ...
drwxr-xr-x  3 alessandra alessandra 4096 Nov 26 10:54 alessandra
... [cut] ...
```

I added this

```
 sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config


Match User alessandra
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    ChrootDirectory /home/alessandra
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

When I connect using SFTP the login is ok, but then I receive (on FileZilla)

```
Error:  FATAL ERROR: Network error: Software caused connection abort
```

So I looked into log files and can see this

```
=> /var/log/auth.log <==
Nov 26 11:09:55 ubuntu sshd[12401]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/home/alessandra"
Nov 26 11:09:55 ubuntu sshd[12368]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user alessandra
```

Why does sshd told me bad ownership ?

How can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved creating a separating folder to chroot into

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/sftp/alessandra
sudo chown root:root /var/sftp
sudo chmod 755 /var/sftp
sudo chown alessandra:alessandra /var/sftp/alessandra
```

then in sshd_config i changed the change root row as this

```
ChrootDirectory /var/sftp
```

Now is working

Paternity of solution: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-sftp-without-shell-access-on-ubuntu-16-04